# Communicating between comments in different sub-trees

Tags: reactjs

I am implementing a Gantt chart editing as a collection of React.js components. I am struggling with how to communicate between components during interactions. For example, when a bar in the Gantt chart is dragged I want to update the dependent bars. Dependent bars probably don't have a parent-child relationship in the DOM - so I need to be able to communicate between relatively unrelated components to get the dependent bars re-rendered in a new location.

I tried setState at the top level and letting the change propagate down through the hierarchy, but this is far too slow while dragging when there are a lot of bars on the screen.

Having each bar/component register event handlers seems like a lot of overhead since each would need to register a handler for a different event (since I only want to update the bars that need to be redrawn).

If I could get a 'pointer' to a component instance I could store that temporarily in the graph data structure that stores the bars. Then I can call setState on only the components that need to be updated.

Are events really the right solution for this situation?

Comment: If you can't use a parent container that updates the children, you could try using something like postal. https://github.com/postaljs

Comment: When you say, "this is far too slow", is that from actually testing it?

Comment: @ssorallen yes, I implemented it first using setState at the root node. When dragging one bar, the re-rendering of all of the other components was enough to make the dragging have too much lag. When I optimized to only re-render the bar being moved the dragged bar stays right with the cursor.

Comment: Right, re-rendering on every mousemove event will be slow regardless of the framework. That's not specifically a React problem. You can either re-render only on `dragend` or throttle the renders to a max of once per some time period, maybe every 500ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I bit the bullet and implemented a pub/sub based solution and it was not as ugly as I had expected.  In fact I can see the decoupling benefit that it provides - now that I have the infrastructure in place I can trigger updates from many other places in the code.

Comment: Did you use any library for the pub/sub implementation or is home-grown?

Comment: just wondering if you ever revised your gantt with flux/redux etc